# How to handle full screen touch interaction with UI elements

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Suppose I have a game where the whole screen is interactable aside from a few UI buttons / elements (i.e. the screen-wide touch handler should be called when touches occur anywhere outside the UI buttons, but not be called when the touch occurs on the UI buttons, since touches occuring on the UI bottons should call the button handler, not the screen-wide touch handler)

What is the best way to block the touch events when the touch occurs on the UI elements?

I've seen multiple approaches...

1. Attach the touch script to an arbitrary gameobject.  In the `Update()` function, check `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)`
   and ignore if it is not false

This seems to be most straight forward and flexible since the `Update()` function can use the `Input` object directly

2. Attach the touch script to a stretched image pane with 0 alpha on back of the canvas and use `OnPointerEnter`, `OnPointerClick`, etc. to handle the touch events

This seems to be the recommended approach under the new GUI system but appears to be less flexible since the raw `Input` values is shielded by the `PointerEventData`, in particular, handling multitouch seems to be tricky with this approach (Also the use of a stretched invisible image at the background of the canvas seems hacky...)

3. Some hybrid of 1 and 2 or other methods?

Since this seems to be an incredibly common thing to do, I'd like to know the industry common practice of such a problem.

Thanks

Related links:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/784617/how-do-i-block-touch-events-from-propagating-throu.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVZiv7DLU6E

Comment: Why do you want to prevent touches on a UI button?Maybe there is a better solution if you explain what you are doing and why a UI button click should be blocked. It is usually a gameobject that people want to block but a ui component..

Comment: I meant that the screen-wide touch script should not be called when the touch occurs on the UI buttons (since touches occuring on the UI bottons should call their own script, not the screen-wide touch script).  Let me clarify that in the question

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such use case of screen-wide touch which goes beyond the methods described in your question. According to natural mapping of interaction, If you have multi-touch interaction model, you should have enough space on screen that user can easily interact without getting close to UI items. Otherwise its not a good interface implementation. So you can use `update()` (method 1 in the OP) to detect tap, swipe, drag and pinch etc. And if you just need single touch (tap) interaction then method 2 is recommended, add a background transparent panel and register `onclick()` listner. So it all depend on your interaction model's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not competent to help in gaming development but would like to offer an idea for consideration:

1. Make v-touch component empty sibling element to its content.
2. Position it absolutely full screen and add CSS pointer-events: none
3. Add to it tap event listener and toggle hide only on tap
4. On underlying content add CSS pointer-events: all and toggle show v-touch on tap.